# Is there a mobile wallet for iOS?

Tags: wallets, tokens, mobile-wallet

I looks like JAXX is only for Android. Is there really no option for iPhone yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JAXX wallet has just entered its iOS Beta. [Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/46nlwy/kryptokit_launches_firstever_ios_ethereum_wallet/).